# Python Split With Delimiter In Field Value

Tags: python, split

I have a "CSV" with which some of the data fields happen to contain the comma delimiter as in the second row of the following sample data.

```
"1","stuff","and","things"
"2","black,white","more","stuff"
```

I can't change the source data and I don't know how to str.split() and not split in the value "black,white".

Ways I've approached my problem:

1. I looked at partition() and don't see how that would benefit me.
2. I'm sure a regex would capture data properly but I'm not sure how to tie one into splitting.
3. Since every row in the source will always have the same number of fields I thought maybe setting maxsplit would help but talked myself out of that with the thinking that it would still split within "black,white" and I would end up loosing the last value (which would be "stuff" in this case).

Certainly this is easy to overcome so I'm looking forward to learning something new!

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at the CSV library included with Python? http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Comment: You forgot to look at the most obvious - the [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Comment: How about line.replace('",', '";').split(';')?

Comment: Regarding the csv module, does it matter that the data isn't truly a csv?  It is sourced from subprocess.

Comment: It should not. If necessary, you can always use a StringIO.

Comment: /me off to experiment with csv, stringio and line.replace as proposed by @FacundoOlano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commas outside the strings are always followed by double-quotes. Just split on `,"` instead of just `,` (or even `","`)

```
>>> x = '"2","black,white","more","stuff"'
>>> x
'"2","black,white","more","stuff"'
>>> x.split(',"')
['"2"', 'black,white"', 'more"', 'stuff"']
>>> [y.strip('"') for y in x.split(',"')]
['2', 'black,white', 'more', 'stuff']
```

Of course, edit for efficiency

YevgenYampolskiy's suggestion of `shlex` is also an alternative.

```
>>> x = '"2","black,white","more","stuff"'
>>> x
'"2","black,white","more","stuff"'
>>> import shlex
>>> y = shlex.shlex(x)
>>> [i.strip('"') for i in y if i != ',']
['2', 'black,white', 'more', 'stuff']
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposed solution and demonstrating an alternative.  I also found line.replace('",', '";').split(';') (presented by @FacundoOlano) cleverly works.

Comment: This will break for fields not enclosed by quotes (which is valid CSV), and may incorrectly handle fields if they have unbalanced quotes. IMHO, the CSV module should be used rather than rolling your own CSV parser.

Comment: @del correct. I was trying to solve user1801810's specific problem more than I was trying to roll my own CSV parser. Maybe I should add a disclaimer?

Comment: @del I appreciate your efforts and will do more evaluation for curiosities sake

Comment: @jsvk I appreciate your efforts and will do more evaluation for curiosities sake

Answer (score 2):

Using [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) and [`StringIO`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stringio.html):

```
>>> import csv, StringIO
>>> data = """"1","stuff","and","things"
... "2","black,white","more","stuff"
... """
>>> reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data))
>>> for row in reader:
...     print row
... 
['1', 'stuff', 'and', 'things']
['2', 'black,white', 'more', 'stuff']
```

Answer (score 1):

If your source is not CSV, and you just want to balance quotes in your string you may try using shlex module:

```
import shlex
lex = shlex.shlex('"2","black,white","more","stuff"')
for i in lex:
    print i
```

Comment: *scratches head* that doesn't seem to do anything, it returns the same data I started with

Comment: It itemizes your input (breaks into logical words). You get "2" as one symbol, and "black,white" as another symbol, etc.